# Creating a parallax effect on a div background, possible to have it alter padding as well?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

So I've created a small parallax scrolling effect on a div for a website I'm building, however I'd like to also be able to alter the padding of the div as well to make the effect a bit more awesome.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
        parallax();
    });
});

function parallax() {
    var scrollPosition = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery('.bg-home').css('background-position','0 '+(0 - (scrollPosition * 0.2))+'px');
}
```

I figured I'd need to do something along these lines:

```
jQuery('.bg-home').css('padding', (scrollPosition - 0.2) +' 0');
```

Here's the issue though, when I'm viewing the top of the page I want the top/bottom padding to be 75px.. when I'm scrolling down I'd want it to slowly go to 0.. how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would take some mathematics to calculate the padding. I believe the formula would look something like this:

```
var padding = 75 - (( $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) * 75);
```

And an attempt to explain:
`$(document).height() - $(window).height()` = the maximum value for scrollTop
`$(window).scrollTop / [max scrollTop]` = the percentage scrolled
`[percentage scrolled] * 75` = when not scrolled, we get 0, when fully scrolled, we get 75
`75 - [percentage scrolled * 75]` = we need 75 when not scrolled, and 0 when fully scrolled, so we subtract from 75

I didn't test it, so feel free to ask if you get stuck.

Comment: First issue it gave me was scrollTop is not defined, I tried adding jQuery(window). in front of it.. not sure if I should've done that?

Also, I think I want it reversed of what it is now. When not scrolled padding should be "75px 0" and the farther down you scroll the smaller the top/bottom padding becomes?

Comment: You are absolutely right about the `$(window).scrollTop()`, my bad. I corrected my answer! No paralax on your website atm, it seems jQuery is not getting loaded...

Comment: The effect is for the main form area's background image on the homepage (yellow/blue)

And the parallax effect itself is working however it's hard to see because of the padding not working correctly.

Comment: I see now, but I ca't seem to locate the actual parallax function in your code. can you add `console.log(padding);` inside the parallax function? And point me towards the file that contains the code? And perhaps we should move this discussion to chat...

Comment: I just found the mistake in my code. I calculated the percentage wrong, the terms should be reversed. See my update (and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nJAYa/)

Comment: It works now! Last question for you, how would I alter this so that it goes from 75px to 0 in the first 600px of scrolling? Thanks again for all your help though, I was very lost on this aspect.

Comment: Figured out a solution myself, removing the document.height - window.height and replacing with a static number works great! Thanks!